# Why do i get the output as 0.0

Tags: c

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    float price;
    float tax=0.05*price;
    float discounted_price=0.05*price+price-0.1*price;

    printf("Enter the total price: ");
    scanf("%f", &price);

    if(price>1000.00)
        printf("congrats you have scored a discount of 10 percent. your total bill amount 
                          is:%0.1f", discounted_price);
    else
        printf("your total bill is:%f",price);
        return 0;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the total price:                                                                                                                                                       
1234                                                                                                                                                                         
congrats you have scored a discount of 10 percent. your total bill amount is:0.0
```

Comment: `price` is uninitialized before use.

Comment: `discounted_price=0.05*price+price-0.1*price;` What do you expect the value of `price` to be at that point?

Comment: Make sure you have everything initialized and compile your code with some basic compilation flags, such as `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` if using `gcc`/`clang`. Consider using [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org/) and [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug your code.

Comment: Your code does not make use of `tax` and does not initialize `price` -- you would be warned about both of these cases if using your compiler *correctly*. Also, please make sure you check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: `float discounted_price=0.05*price+price-0.1*price;` sets `discounted_price` according to the value of the expression *at that time*.  Changing `price` later won't update `discounted_price`.

Comment: Note: Usually tax is calculated on the discounted price, not the pre-discounted one.

Answer (score 0):

put this assignment `discounted_price=0.05*price+price-0.1*price;` after `scanf("%f", &price);` and you'll get right result, otherwise before you type a number as price, the discounted_price has been set to an uninitialized value already.

**your prolbem is calculating the discounted_price before you get it! In your code, you first calculate discounted_price by "discounted_price=0.05*price+price-0.1*price;", and then you read a number from keyboard by "scanf("%f", &price)". The value of price is unknown when you use it by "discounted_price=0.05*price+price-0.1*price", so your result of discounted_price is wrong.**

Comment: @ojaswi What do you expect the default value of an automatic to be?

Comment: @ojaswi It's not necessarily `0`. A variable like `float price;` is left uninitialized, and could have any value, including invalid values that could trigger floating point exceptions. You *must* initialize `price` before using it, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @ojaswi dxiv was right. but your prolbem is calculating the discounted_price before you get it! In your code, you first calculate discounted_price by "discounted_price=0.05*price+price-0.1*price;", and then you read a number from keyboard by "scanf("%f", &price)". The value of price is unknown when you use it by "discounted_price=0.05*price+price-0.1*price", so your result of discounted_price is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This happen cause you are trying to calculate the value from price while price is not initialize so for that you have to get the price first then you can calculate from it

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    float price;
    float tax = 0.0f;
    float discounted_price = 0.0f;

    printf("Enter the total price: ");
    scanf("%f", &price);

    tax = 0.05f * price;
    discounted_price = 0.05*price+price-0.1*price;
    
    if(price>1000.00)
        printf("congrats you have scored a discount of 10 percent. your total bill amount is:%0.1f", discounted_price);
    else
        printf("your total bill is:%f",price);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in the above code first we take value from the user then we calculate the tax and discount price.